# Ubuntu 14.04 will not update/remove or install any packages

Tags: apt, updates

I first noticed this problem when my update manager kept failing to install updates sudo apt-get update runs without returning any errors, when i run:

```
sudo apt-get install upgrade
```

i get the following error:

```
dpkg: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

And probably unrealated to this problem when i first boot up my computer (same laptop as above error) the 'T' and 'Y' keys and a few other keys do not work, originally thought it was a problem with the keyboard itself but all keys start working normally after a few mins my guess is a software problem?

I tried doing some searching around but could not find a solution to either problem, i am hoping someone will be able to help

Comment: The right commands, actually, are: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the machine in recovery mode (basically yank power twice), then pick advanced options, recovery mode, and try the dpkg option. Worth a try.

Comment: Tried it, still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

The right command is

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You should remove the install and it will work.

Comment: That was my mistake in typing the post it

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the very same error and I managed to find a solution.

As you can probably infer from the error message, this is an issue with dpkg.
It turns out, in my case, there was a corrupted file in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` that caused dpkg to end in such a dramatical way. The easiest and less dangerous solution is to reinstall the system, but if this is too much pain you may try to remove the corrupted file by rebuilding the info.

First create a backup.

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg
mv info info.bak
```

Now you may regenerate the info by reinstalling every package in the system. (Warning: this is going to take a while!)

```
for i in $(dpkg -l|awk '/^ii/ {print $2}')
do
    apt-get --reinstall -y install $i
done
```

Hopefully you are all set!

(this last step is from https://serverfault.com/questions/484933/debian-removed-var-lib-dpkg-info-is-there-a-way-to-save-the-system)